# Why do these equations in (with central force) two body problems seem self-contradictory?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centrifugal-force

The following materials are from Kleppner's book, p. 377, eq. (10.4)

[image]

The handwriting is my derivation.

($\mu$  refers to reduced mass, $r$ is the position vector of the "equivalent one body" or $r_{12}$, $U$ is the 'normal' potential.)

As you can see, according to the second equation, which is obtain from the first one, there is a minus sign. However, when differentiating the equation of energy, I get a positive sign (and so does the "official" solution manual).

Could anyone please tell me what went wrong?

Comment: -1 is for illegible equations. Please use [$\LaTeX$ syntax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type easy to read equations on this site.

Comment: Comment to the post (v5): Note that the minus sign in Kleppner's  eq. (10.4a) is physically meaningful. Eq. (10.4a) is the radial Newton's 2nd law: It says that mass times acceleration $\mu \ddot{r}$ is the sum of the central force $f(r)$ and the centrifugal force $\mu r\dot{\theta}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where you're running into a problem. In the equation: $$\frac{\operatorname{d} E}{\operatorname{d} t} = \dot{r} \left(\mu \ddot{r} + r \dot{\theta}^2 + \frac{\partial U}{\partial r}\right) = 0,$$
there are two solutions. First, is the one you're examining with $$\mu \ddot{r} + r \dot{r} \dot{\theta}^2 + \frac{\partial U}{\partial r} = 0$$ the other is for $\dot{r}=0$.

That is only a minor difficulty, though. The major difficulty lies in the fact that you missed the term with $\ddot{\theta}$ in it. The correct time derivative of $E$ is:
$$\frac{\operatorname{d} E}{\operatorname{d} t} =  \mu \dot{r} \ddot{r} + r \dot{r} \dot{\theta}^2 + \dot{r}^2 \dot{\theta} \ddot{\theta} + \dot{r}\frac{\partial U}{\partial r}.$$ That is enough to make the contradiction vanish when you apply the second, $\hat{\theta}$, equation at the top of your question. You can also see that if $\ddot{\theta}=0$ then $\dot{r}=0$ or $\dot{\theta}=0$. The former means that your derivation had a divide by $0$ error, or the term that has the plus or minus is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Have you differentiated the term $r^2 \dot \theta^2$ correctly?

You then get rid of the $\ddot \theta$ by using the third equation from Kleppner $r \ddot \theta +2 \dot r \dot \theta = 0$ and your sign change will arrive as required.